# How to use nullptr properly?

Tags: c++, nullptr

currently I am reading "A tour of C++" by Byarne Stroustrup. The thing that matters: on "pointers, arrays and references" he gave an example about using `nullptr` like this:

```
int count_x(char* p, char x)
// count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
// p is assumed to point to a zero-terminated array of char (or to nothing)
{

    if (p == nullptr) return 0;
        int count = 0;

    for (; p != nullptr; ++p)
        if (*p == x)
            ++count;

    return count;
}
```

In my my main:

```
int main(){

    char* str = "Good morning!";
    char c = 'o';
    std::cout << count_x(str, c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it crashes I get an exception thrown at line

```
if (*p == x)
```

If I change the loop to be like this:

```
for (; *p; p++)
    if (*p == x)
        ++count;
```

Now everything works fine! I am using MSVC++ 14.0.

- The same code I ran on `ideone` I don't get an exception but the result is always `0` which should be `3`:

https://ideone.com/X9BeVx

Comment: @DeiDei: Yes I just copied and pasted the code. What I add is main code.

Comment: @DeiDei: How should this be correct: `*p != nullptr`? as I guess `nullptr` is only for addresses pointers point to not a the value they sore in address they point to.

Comment: I didn't find this in any of the errata's for "A tour of C++". You should write to Bjarne and let him know. This is a mistake.

Comment: The code from this [online version](https://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf#page=11) uses a correct check - where did you copy your code from?

Comment: @hnefatl: Yes that is correct. But I don't know why my book is incorrect? It is in extension "epub". Thank you.

Comment: BTW, `char* str = "Good morning!";` is not a valid C++ code. `str` should be of type `const char*`. MSVC++ is too permissive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`p != nullptr` and `*p` perform very different checks.

The former checks that the pointer itself contains a non-null address. While the latter checks that the address being pointed at contains something that is not 0. One is clearly appropriate in the loop, where the buffer's content is checked, while the other is not.

You segfault because you never stop reading the buffer (a valid pointer is unlikely to produce null when it is incremented). So you end up accessing way beyond your buffer limit.

Comment: But this is considered incorrect: `*p = nullptr` isn't it?

Comment: @WonFeiHong - Yes, that would be incorrect. `*p` doesn't have a pointer type, so it won't be possible to compare it with `nullptr`. You'll get a compiler error when you try

Comment: Yeah if you want to make the comparison more explicit you can do *p != '\0' though just *p works fine too...

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are using C language feature.

Your problem is in your `for` loop. After the pointer reaches the last element of your **character array** it points to the end of the array not the `nullptr`.

Imagine you have a character array such as `const char *a ="world"` and `ptr` points to the

```
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
ptr :| *======>  | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
     +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

the last element which **ptr** points to is `'\0'` and in your `for` you should change your code as below:

---

```
for (; *p != 0; p++) {
        if (*p == x)
            ++count;
    }
```

output : 3